# How to show one class by default on page load and when hovered to another block hide the default one and show another block when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Guys i stuck at a problem where i want to show one block default on page load and another to show when hovered and hide the default one until the another blocks are being hovered. i wrote this code to add class and remove class but instead of removing classes when hovered on one block it shows every of them at same time the content in the middle is what I wanted to show,

Thanks.

[image]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.eael-image-accordion-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-1').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-2').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-3').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-4').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-5').removeClass('active');
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.eael-image-accordion-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-2').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-1').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-3').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-4').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-5').removeClass('active');
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.eael-image-accordion-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-3').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-1').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-2').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-4').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-5').removeClass('active');
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.eael-image-accordion-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-4').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-1').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-2').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-3').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-5').removeClass('active');
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.eael-image-accordion-hover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-5').addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.why-us-1').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-2').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-3').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('.why-us-4').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Some refinement suggestions: `jQuery(document).ready(function()` >>> `jQuery(function($) {}` | `$('.why-us-1, .why-us-2, .why-us-3, .why-us-4').removeClass('active');` | All your code can be in one `.ready` block.

Comment: Please revise and edit the snippet to include some HTML. There's probably a lot more that can be cleaned up here. There's a crazy amount of repetition up there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue thanks to @isherwood suggestion I have used this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.why-us-1').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.why-us-1').addClass('active');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.why-us-2, .why-us-3, .why-us-4, .why-us-5').removeClass('active');     
       });
   });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.why-us-2').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.why-us-2').addClass('active');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.why-us-1, .why-us-3, .why-us-4, .why-us-5').removeClass('active');     
       });
   });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.why-us-3').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.why-us-3').addClass('active');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.why-us-1, .why-us-2, .why-us-4, .why-us-5').removeClass('active');     
       });
   });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.why-us-4').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.why-us-4').addClass('active');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.why-us-1, .why-us-2, .why-us-3, .why-us-5').removeClass('active');     
       });
   });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.why-us-5').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.why-us-5').addClass('active');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.why-us-1, .why-us-2, .why-us-3, .why-us-4').removeClass('active');     
       });
   });
```